# Bash Bug? Can't use negate extglob !(*/) to filter out directories?

Tags: bash, shell

If the glob `*/` only matches directories, then logically the extglob `!(*/)` should match non-directories; but this doesn't work.  Is this a bug or am I missing something?  Does this work on any shell?

#### Test 1 to prove that `*/` works

```
$ cd /tmp; ls -ld */
drwxr-xr-x  2 seand users 4096 Jan  1 15:59 test1//
drwxr-xr-x  2 seand users 4096 Jan  1 15:59 test2//
drwxr-xr-x  2 seand users 4096 Jan  1 15:59 test3//
```

#### Test 2 to show potential bug with `!(*/)`

```
$ cd /tmp; shopt -s extglob; ls -ld !(*/)
/bin/ls: cannot access !(*/): No such file or directory
```

Comment: +1..Interesting observation. I just verified your observation and it turns out you were right.

Comment: +1 Same here. Will be glad to know the right answer. :-)

Comment: I believe globs work on filenames, the fact that `*/` matches directories is because the pattern forms a valid path but the glob still applies to the filename alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bash, `!()` (like `*`, `?`, `*()`, and `@()`) only applies to one path component.  Thus, `!(anything containing a / slash)` doesn't work.

If you switch to [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/), you can use `*(^/)` to match all non-directories, or `*(.)` to match all plain files.

Comment: Can you further elaborate on what you mean by *only one path component*

Comment: Thanks for explaining why I couldn't get `?(/boot/vmlinuz*)` to work! Only `/boot/?(vmlinuz*)` managed to work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the specific question has already been given; and I am not sure if you really wanted another solution or if you were just interested to analyze the behavior, but one way to list all non-directories in the current folder is to use find:

```
find . ! -type d -maxdepth 1
```